# Theme does not toggle

Tags: android, android-theme, android-menu

I am trying to toggle between the themes. I looked into the HoneyCombGallery sample code and found out the code to toggle between themes. But it is not working in my application.

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean success = true;
    private int mThemeId = -1;
Button btnViewLib;
Button btnlog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getInt("theme", -1) != -1) {
        mThemeId = savedInstanceState.getInt("theme");
        this.setTheme(mThemeId);
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnViewLib = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlib);
    btnlog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlog);


    btnViewLib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching All products Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LibActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    btnlog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching All products Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.toggleTheme:
        if (mThemeId == R.style.AppTheme_Dark) {
            mThemeId = R.style.AppTheme_Light;
        } else {
            mThemeId = R.style.AppTheme_Dark;
        }
        this.recreate();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

  <!-- Example of items in the overflow menu -->
  <item android:id="@+id/toggleTheme"
    android:title="@string/theme_toggle"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

 </menu>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar" />

<style name="ActionBar.Light" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Dark" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme should be set before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` call.

EDIT:

And if you want to get something from `savedInstanceState`, you should first save something in there. So you need to override onSaveInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putInt("theme", mThemeId );

}
```

Comment: Still not working. In HoneyCombGallrey sample project it's done this way only.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or it just isn't working? You can try `setTheme(R.styles.AppTheme.Light)` instead of this if statement and see if it will work.

Comment: I used Log.i("Theme", "Dark Selected"); to see if the "if else" statement is executing properly or not. It seems that only else is being executed everytime i select from menu. Any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: You are trying to get your Theme from savedInstanceState in your `OnCreate()` method, but you are not saving it there. You should override `onSaveInstanceState()` method and save your `mThemeId`.

Comment: Well in android manifest if i exclusively start off with Dark theme, it works but still does not toggle. So it clearly shows that dark theme is working but not toggling which means there is something wrong with "if else".

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how do i achieve this?